# Syntax to remove attribute from an element

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

Is there a way to remove an attribute from an element? I know an attribute can be replaced as shown below.

```
var node = new NodeBuilder();
node.addAttribute("myAttribute", "attributeValue");     
xdmp.nodeReplace(attributeElement.getAttributeNode("myAttribute"),node.toNode());
```

But I want to completely remove the attribute from an element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for [xdmp.nodeDelete](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.nodeDelete).

It may sound a bit strange, but it also works on attributes:

```
declareUpdate();
xdmp.documentInsert("/test.xml", xdmp.unquote('<test a="x" b="y">text</test>'));
```

followed by:

```
declareUpdate();
xdmp.nodeDelete(cts.doc("/test.xml").xpath("/test/@a"))
```

Keep in mind though, these functions only work on nodes persisted in the database.

HTH!

Comment: I do not want to delete node. I just want to delete an attribute from the node.